# errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed" - mariadb

Tags: mariadb

Well, I'm going to be clear.

I'm trying to create another table where one of the fields references to the second one. The 'parent' table was created by the forum software I installed on my webserver. However, when I try to reference the new table, it drops me `errorno: 150`.

The field I'm trying to reference is `name`

I downloaded the db created by the forum software to see exactly which kind of attributes are added while creating the table of that specific field.
They are the following one:

```
CREATE TABLE `core_members` (
  `member_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `core_members`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`member_id`),
  ADD KEY `name_index` (`name`(191));
```

**And this is how I am creating and referencing the new table:**

```
create table testtable (
`name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
);

ALTER TABLE testtable ADD INDEX(`name`);

ALTER TABLE testtable ADD FOREIGN KEY (`name`) REFERENCES core_members(`name`) ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

I hope you can bring me a hand with this issue.
Thanks for reading, best regards.

**EDIT**: Im using MariaDB 10.3.34: https://i.stack.imgur.com/euE5d.png

Comment: It would be better if you posted the table schema, that is the definitive status of your database

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @RohitGupta Here is a screenshot about the scheme https://i.imgur.com/iAGOtzZ.png

Comment: Why are you creating an index like this: `name_index (name(191))`?

Comment: @mustaccio - He is running 5.5 or 5.6 and using utf8mb4.  Cf: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes

Comment: @mustaccio I didn't create that index, As I said, the forum software where I am working, during installation creates all the tables...etc The issue comes when I try to create a custom table that reference to one of the created by the forum software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/foreign-keys/ says:

> Index prefixes are not supported

I suggest that `name` doesn't have to be `varchar(255)`. It could be a shorter string. It's quite rare for a name to require such a long field. I know the Guinness record holder for the longest name is over 600 characters, but he can choose a shortened version of his name.

In fact, in virtually every case where I see someone use `varchar(255)` in a database, they should have used either a more sensible length, or else a `text` field.

---

I also find that in MariaDB 10.3, the default InnoDB row format allows indexes for a column up to 3072 bytes. The software you are installing was apparently designed for an older version that only allows indexes for a column up to 767 bytes.

Demo of your test case, but I simply removed the `(191)` part, and made an index on the whole `name` column. It works on MariaDB 10.3.

https://dbfiddle.uk/xG80cTgV

I understand that you don't want to modify the table created by the forum software.

The alternative is to make a foreign key that references that table's primary key, instead of the index on `name`. This would be better, in fact.

InnoDB allows a nonstandard usage of foreign keys, to reference an index that is not a primary key or unique key. But this leads to some weird cases, like what if the name you reference occurs on multiple rows in `core_members`? What does that mean for a foreign key? If someone updates or deletes one of those names, does it conflict with your foreign key? What if you declare your foreign key with cascading options, should it do the cascade if one of the rows changes but not the other?

I recommend you avoid these questions by referencing the primary key only:

```
ALTER TABLE testtable
  ADD COLUMN member_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (`member_id`) REFERENCES core_members(`member_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: Yep, I know that the field could be shorter, but, the paren't table wasn't created by me. It was created by the forum software during the installation. However, Im a bit worried that if I changes that it could break something related names ...etc